# Importing libraries into jupyter causes it to error: the kernel appears to have died

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

Doing something as simple as:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Causes Jupyter Notebook to crash with: `the kernel appears to have died`.

I have tested:

```
import sys

sys.version
```

Which correctly imports sys, and prints version 3.9.

Trying a few other libraries such as `matplotlib`, `seaborn`, and `numpy` gives the same error.

I have tried installing these liraries in the terminal in jupyter with `conda install package`, but they are already installed. I have also checked they are up-to-date, which they are.

I'm using the Macbook Air M1 chip, with Anaconda x64 installed.

Not sure what to do from here.